# Cannot add an object to a state tree if it is already part of the same or another state tree

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

> mobx-state-tree.module.js?f7d3:2154 Uncaught Error: [mobx-state-tree] Cannot add an object to a state tree if it is already part of the same or another state tree.

I get this error just by filtering through another state:

```
const data = self.allData.slice(0, 20);
self.sliced = data
```

Anyone has any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A node cannot exist twice in the state tree. You could instead model your `sliced` data as an array of [`references`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/references) and it should work as expected.

**Example**

```js
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const Thing = types.model({
  id: types.identifier
});

const RootStore = types
  .model({
    allData: types.array(Thing),
    sliced: types.maybe(types.array(types.reference(Thing)))
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    setSliced() {
      const data = self.allData.slice(0, 20);
      self.sliced = data;
    }
  }));

const rootStore = RootStore.create({
  allData: Array.from({ length: 40 }, (_, index) => ({ id: index.toString() }))
});

console.log(rootStore.sliced); // undefined
rootStore.setSliced();
console.log(rootStore.sliced); // (20) [Object, Object, ...]
```

Comment: I got another error:

mobx-state-tree.module.js?f7d3:2154 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting

Comment: @Rollin That's frustrating. Consider accepting this answer and create a new question, since that is a new error unrelated to your original question.